# Printing array of struct Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I'm trying to print my struct. I want it to show:

```
id: BBB-188
brand: BMW
pic: 1 2 3.
```

Right now the result is this:

```
id: BBB-188 
name: BMW 
Segmentation fault: 11.
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```c
#define MAX 10000
#define IDSIZE 11
#define BRANDSIZE 50
#define PICSIZE 10

typedef struct{
    char id[IDSIZE+1];
    char brand[BRANDSIZE+1];
    int *pic;
} Car;

void printCar(Car *pCar,int carcount, int imagecount) {  
    printf("id: %s \n",pCar->id);
    printf("brand: %s \n",pCar->brand);
    for(int i=0; i< imagecount; i++){
        printf("pic: %d \n",pCar->pic[i]);
    }
}

Car initCar(char itsId[],char itsBrand[],int itsPic, int     imagecount){
    Car newCar;
    strcpy(newCar.id, itsId);
    strcpy(newCar.brand, itsBrand);
    for (int i = 0; i < imagecount; i++){
        newCar.pic = itsPic;
    }
    return newCar;
}

int main(void){
    int carcount=0;
    int imagecount=0;

    int test[3]={1,2,3};

    Car myCar = initCar("BBB-188","BMW", test, 3 );

    carcount=1;
    imagecount=3;

    printCar(&myCar,carcount,imagecount);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The handling of `pic` is broken and very confusing.

You seem to want to represent it as an array of integers, but you don't store the length. Thus it has to be always three, but then you can just use an array in the structure, i.e.:

```
int pic[3];
```

instead of

```
int *pic;
```

Also the assignment inside `initCar()` makes no sense, you're looping but simply assigning the same integer value (!) to the pointer `imagecount` times, no data is being copied.

If you want the length of the picture array to really be variable, you must store the length and allocate memory for holding the numbers. So in `initCar()` you must have:

```
newCar.pic = malloc(imagecount * sizeof *newCar.pic);
memcpy(newCar.pic, itsPic, imagecount * sizeof *newCar.pic);
```

but then `itsPic` must of course be of type `const int *`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `itsPic` as a pointer in `initCar`. If you're doing so, you don't need the `for` loop for the affectation.

```
Car initCar(char itsId[],char itsBrand[],int* itsPic, int imagecount){
    Car newCar;
    strcpy(newCar.id, itsId);
    strcpy(newCar.brand, itsBrand);
    //for (int i = 0; i < imagecount; i++){
      newCar.pic = itsPic;
    //}
    return newCar;
}
```